# Why HTML standard Reset button cannot reset asp.net form's value?

Tags: asp.net, reset

Why can't the HTML reset button reset an ASP.NET form directly? Why do we need to write extra code to achieve the Reset function for an ASP.NET form?

I am looking for an explanation behind this.

Comment: .net known for it stat maintaining

Comment: `<input type='Reset'/>` is not a server control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

asp.net maintains its values in something called the 'ViewState'.

This remembers values you have assigned to an input, so if you want to reset inputs, you have to clear them yourself.

You should read [Understanding asp.net ViewState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972976.aspx)

> view state, in a nutshell, is the technique used by an ASP.NET Web
>   page to persist changes to the state of a Web Form across postbacks.
>   The view state of a page is, by default, placed in a hidden form field
>   named __VIEWSTATE.  View state's purpose in life is simple: it's there
>   to persist state across postbacks. (For an ASP.NET Web page, its state
>   is the property values of the controls that make up its control
>   hierarchy.)

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this code

```
<asp:TextBox id="tbx" runat="server" Text="Test"/>
<asp:Button id="btn" runat="server" OnClick="ResetEventHandler" Text="Reset"/>

void ResetEventHandler(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   tbx.Text = string.Empty;

}
```

You don't have reset control in .net

Answer (score 0):

HTML is basically used for static display of your data . Resetting all the text means your server has to reload the data making some changes to it . For example , you have put in a text field(ID=txt1) with EnableViewState property as True . Now if you are using HTML you cannot make change in its state so use the following code:-

```
protected void Reset_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)//button in UI
  {
    gvEmployee2.Visible = false;//If you have a grid and you want to reset it 
     txt1.Text = string.Empty; // Reset Text Box alternative :- txt1.Text = " ";
    }
   }
```

Answer (score -2):

```
 protected void btnreset_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {       
        try
        {
            Clear();
            button1.Text = "button1";

        }
        catch (Exception)

        {}
     }

}
```